# How to enable INMEMORY JOIN GROUP in Oracle 12.2

Tags: oracle, memory-optimized-tables, in-memory-database

I have read official Oracle documentation on INMEMORY JOIN GROUP and run code from their tutorials. However I unable to successfully create INMEMORY JOIN GROUP.

- Installed database is Oracle 12.2
- INMEMORY TABLE and INMEMORY COLUMN were created successfully.

Exception message of INMEMORY JOIN GROUP creation below:

```
Error starting at line : 1 in command -
CREATE INMEMORY JOIN GROUP employees_departments
    (employees(department_id), departments())
Error report -
ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement
00900. 00000 -  "invalid SQL statement"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

My code is

```
CREATE INMEMORY JOIN GROUP employees_departments
    (employees(department_id), departments());
```

Are there any Oracle initialize parameters that should be specified in order to turn on support of INMEMORY JOIN GROUP?

Oracle SQL Developer highlights INMEMORY as incorrect syntax:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you need also a column for the `departments table`

> ```
> CREATE TABLE employees(department_id int)
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TAble departments(department_id int)
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> CREATE INMEMORY JOIN GROUP employees_departments
>     (employees(department_id), departments(department_id));
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=d831fd78de41aee909b4025d9574353f)*